# Ruby: How to write a bang method, like map?

Tags: ruby, self

I'd like to write some new Array methods that alter the calling object, like so:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
a.map!{|e| e+1}
a = [2,3,4,5]
```

...but I'm blanking on how to do this.  I think I need a new brain.

So, I'd like something like this:

```
class Array
  def stuff!
    # change the calling object in some way
  end
end
```

map! is just an example, I'd like to write a completely fresh one without using any pre-existing ! methods.

Thanks!

Comment: You'd just modify the instance's attributes (properties, whatever) (and probably return the same instance). Where's the mental block coming?

Comment: Hmm, let me re-write it a little.  I changed it to re-open the Array class.  The question is how to access the instance's attributes when you didn't write your own attributes, I suppose.. for native ruby classes like Array and String.

Comment: I am sure you have a good reason to update objects in-place, but you know about functional programming, don't you?

Comment: Well, now I do.  : )  Back when I wrote this, it was out of curiosity more than for any real project-based requirement.  I think I was wondering if it were possible, in case I encountered a situation where it would be a good idea.  I've since discovered Haskell and Erlang and friends, and wish more jobs were available for those languages... I'd love to do functional programming all day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT** - Updated answer to reflect the changes to your question.

```
class Array
  def stuff!
        self[0] = "a"
  end
end

foo = [1,2,3,4]

foo.stuff!

p foo #=> ['a',2,3,4]
```

Comment: Does this mean I can't write my own bang methods without using a pre-existing bang method? (read: "bang method" as "thing that changes the calling object itself".  I have a suspicion that this is only done at the C level.

Comment: Sure you can.  You can do something like: `self[0] = "a"` (see my edits)

Comment: Excellent!  I tried this also with `String`, but came up with some oddities... more experimentation required.  I know you can access strings like arrays, but that seems a convoluted way of changing value of self for a String.

Comment: I haven't been able to find documentation or any reference material on this topic.  Anyone know of anything I can read to learn more about this specific thing?

Answer (score 1):

```
def stuff!
  self.something = 'something else'
end
```

bam, you've modified the underlying object without returning a new object

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind.  I clarified a little in the original post.  : )