# Ruby: Reference materials to learn more about assigning values to self

Tags: ruby, reference, self

I haven't been able to find documentation or any reference material on this topic: [Ruby: How to write a bang method, like map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665497/ruby-how-to-write-a-bang-method-like-map)

Anyone know of anything I can read to learn more about this *specific* thing?

**EDIT:** In light of the comments, I'm amending this question as follows:

So, we discovered that Arrays and Strings can be manipulated through this array notation of self:

```
self[i]=
```

But that's not the whole story behind manipulating the **value** of self.  There are plenty of reference materials about the scope of self and what it means in its current context, but there isn't much I've found about `self` manipulation methods.

What if I wanted to write my own version of `String`'s `chomp!` or other bang method?  Am I locked into using `self[0]...self[i]`?  What about other classes?

Thanks!

Comment: There really isn't much more to learn. `self` is a reference to the object you're currently "inside." You can operate on `self` just like you would any other object (but can also access private and protected methods directly). If you want to know more, most of the links on the first page of this Google search are really solid: http://www.google.com/search?q=ruby+self+object

Comment: Yes, but although you can access a string by `self[0]=`, that only gets you the first character.  `self=` isn't a valid operation, unfortunately.  There really isn't much about `self[0]` or things like it in those links.  I'll keep trudging through the internet and ruby books, though.

Comment: I found some references to it in [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781934356470.do), but still no info on manipulating a `String`.

Comment: Excellent question!  I've been trying to do do this for a while (to write an Object.nil= method that overwrites self only if it's nil, unlike ||=, which also overwrites false).  But I'm beginning to suspect it's only doable in a lower-level language, like C...

Comment: @wulftone You didn't mention manipulating strings previously. What, specifically, are you trying to do?

Comment: @jordan True, I didn't in the examples, but I found it curious that Array offered a convenient way to manipulate `self`, but String did not.  Sure I could use `self[i]` and manipulate a string by iterating over each character, but it seems like an odd way to do it.  In any case, it would be interesting if you could change the calling object into a new object of a different class, like a `s="42"; s.to_i!; s.class #=> 'Fixnum'` kind of scenario.  Anyway, I was curious because I saw in browsing apidock.com things like `chomp!` are written in C, and sometimes it would be nice to do that operation.

Comment: ...on my own custom function.  I didn't want to limit my question to only Arrays or Strings though.

Comment: I understand what you're saying now. You could implement your own version of e.g. `String#chomp!` but eventually you'd have to fall back on one of those C-based bang methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read the [article in Wikipedia about self](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_(computer_science)) (even if it does not mention Ruby at all).

To make a long story short:

- Ruby has borrowed a lot of concepts from other languages, and `self` comes from Smalltalk.
- `self` is called in Smalltalk a pseudo-variable, which means it is variable, but it is set by the runtime environment, not by the program or programmer.
- `self` references all the time the receiver of a message. `super` references the superclass of that message that is implemented by the method the reference `super` is in. (Glad that you did not ask for `super`).
- `self` in Ruby (as in Smalltalk) references all the time the current object, and that may be an instance of a class or even a class itself. So if you define methods on the class-side (only callable on the class), even there `self` references the object, which is the class. So it is possible in Ruby to use only `self`, you never have to write down the name of the class to denote the receiver. That helps a little bit when refactoring.

If you have get all that, take a look at [Metaprogramming Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476) which tells you some more tricks how to use `self`, classes, eigenclasses and some other interesting things.

Comment: This is the most complete example, but not comprehensive.  I still haven't found one single place that defines _all_ (really, ALL) of the ways to use `self` in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

(Since this is a little long for a comment...)

Indeed, you can't change the value of `self`, but you can change properties on `self`, which is what's happening in your example.

Let me elaborate. Say you have a class `Foo` and you do something like this:

```
f = Foo.new
f.bar = 3
puts f.bar # => 9
```

"`2`"?? What's actually happening here is that you're calling a method `bar=` on `f` with the argument `1`. The method `bar=` could look something like this:

```
class Foo
  def bar=(val)
    @bar = val**2 # square the given value and assign it to the instance
  end             # variable @bar

  def bar
    @bar          # return the instance variable @bar -- a shortcut for this is
  end

  # we could get rid of the second method, though, but using attr_reader:
  attr_reader :bar
end
```

Okay, so what about this?

```
f = Foo.new
puts f[5] # => 10
```

"`10`"?! Yep. Again, `[]` is just [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for a plain old method. Something like this:

```
class Foo
  def [](val)
    val * 2 # Ruby just takes the value you put between [] and gives it to you as
  end       # the first parameter
end
```

And finally:

```
f = Foo.new
f[:bar] = 99
puts f[:bar] # => 100
```

Yep, you guessed it, this is just another method call. For example:

```
class Foo
  @my_hash = {}

  def []=(key, val)         # Ruby gives us the value between the [] as the first
    @my_hash[key] = val + 1 # parameter and the value after the = as the second,
  end                       # and we use them to set a value on an internal
                            # instance variable...
  def [](key)
    @my_hash[key]           # ...and we can use the "getter" to get a value from 
  end                       # the instance variable.
end
```

You're right, this stuff isn't all covered in one single, convenient source, so I hope this helps. Feel free to comment if you need further explanation.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I was asking, and it's also pretty questionable practice... I would _never_ want `f[:bar] = 99` to output 100 the next time I call it--the same goes for the other examples where you're overriding the commonly accepted behavior of a "setter."  I'd instead make a function called `increment(key)` and have it increment `@my_hash`.  Downvoting so people don't think you have a good idea, and for missing the question.  Sorry.

Comment: My answer wasn't a description of what I thought anyone *should* do, it was an illustration of how methods like `[]` and `[]=` are just regular method calls. It doesn't answer your question--as we discussed in the comments--so I don't expect an upvote or even care about your downvote, but I don't appreciate your saying I don't "have a good idea." It's an *illustration*. You would know more write this exact code than you would name a class "Foo," and I think that's obvious to anyone who might come along and read it.