# How to create bang method that modifies the argument

Tags: ruby

I want to create a bang method `preload!` that takes an argument and modifies it like this:

```
hash = Hash.new
preload! hash
# => Now `hash` should have some value
```

How can I do it?

```
def preload! param 
  param = # Some values
end
```

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665497/ruby-how-to-write-a-bang-method-like-map), but I'm not going to encapsulate `preload!` in `Hash` class.

Comment: Considering your method **must** be encapsulated in a class, I'm not sure what you're asking is clear.

Comment: @depa I dont want preload method to be defined in Hash class and modify it by `self.value=` kinda trick. Hope you get it

Comment: If there is no caller to change, bang is not meaningful.

Comment: does ruby has pass by reference ?

Comment: @shiva in Ruby arguments are always passed by reference

Comment: Ruby doesn't have any concept of passing a value around. Variables are always references to objects.

Comment: bang methods in ruby modify `self` not parameters.

Comment: Methods must be defined before using them.

Comment: You probably don't want to do it like that. Methods that modify their arguments are considered bad practice. Readers of your code will assume `preload!` to modify the callee (that is a convention in Ruby), not the arguments, and will be puzzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the object passed as argument, but you have to use the appropriate methods to modify the receiver:

```
def preload! hash 
  hash.replace(foo: 1, bar: 2)
end

h = {}
preload! h
h #=> {:foo=>1, :bar=>2}
```

Assigning a new hash to `hash` inside `preload!` just affects the `hash` variable inside the method, not the `h` variable outside:

```
def preload! hash 
  hash = {foo: 1, bar: 2} # doesn't work as expected
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def preload! param 
  param.replace(<key value pair that you need>)
end

hash = Hash.new    # hash = {}

preload! hash      # Now hash should have some value
```

Comment: You should define the method *before* calling it.

Comment: Oops, just made use of OP's code.

Comment: As suggested by @Stefan, the proper methods should be used to modify the receiver. Replace is the correct method here rather than merge!. Edited my answer.

Comment: `Hash#merge!` modifies the receiver, too!

Comment: yeah, but what if preload! is used after the hash has been already populated some other key value pair. Say something like, `h = {:foo => 1}`. And after that he calls the preload! method. I just felt that this won't serve the purpose what OP wants.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna how about `params.replace(params.merge(foo: 1, bar: 2))` ?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you are trying to do but `instance_eval` should give you that flexibility

```
def mutator! object
  object.instance_eval do 
    def to_s
      'bonk'
    end
  end
end

h = {}
h.to_s # => {}
mutator! h
h.to_s # => bonk
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying, smells bad.  Instead of modifying your arguments, you should prolly do something like this

```
class HashPreloader
  attr_reader :hash

  def initialize(hash)
    @hash = hash || {}
    preload!
  end

  private

  def preload!
    # do your magic
  end
end
```

And then just

```
hash = HashPreloader.new.hash
```

To elaborate further, I would need to know more about the use case.  What are you actually trying to do.